# TYPO3 with extbase: UriBuilder (or something similar) in backend hook

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I wrote a backend hook in TYPO3 (with extbase) for sending an email when certain values of a table are set. What I need to do in my hook now is generate a frontend URL. But I cannot seem to get a hold of the UriBuilder. How do I build a valid frontend url in a backend hook context? What I tried is this:

```
$uriBuilder = $objectManager->get('\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\Routing\UriBuilder');
$link = $uriBuilder->setTargetPageUid($this->formPageId)->buildFrontendUri();
```

which results in the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function typoLink_URL() on a non-object in /data/www/path/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Web/Routing/UriBuilder.php on line 640
```

What the heck does this mean? I also tried calling $uriBuilder->initializeObject(), but the error remains the same. Am I going about this totally the wrong way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, but god knows this feels way too convoluted to be right. What I did was create a frontend ajax call in my Extension and in my backend hook I called the ajax page to fetch the url:

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
$libDiv = $objectManager->get('\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility');
$siteUrl = 'http://domain.com/';
//now set the ajax url
$url = $siteUrl.'index.php?type=1447752540&id='.$this->ajaxPageId;
//set headers because otherwise it doesn't work
$headers = array(
    'Cookie: fe_typo_user=' . $_COOKIE['fe_typo_user']
);
//as far as I understand it, this is the equivalent of file_get_contents
$result = $libDiv::getURL($url, false, $headers);
```

and my plugin does nothing but call the uribuilder and generate the desired link.

...I feel so dirty.

Answer (score 3):

Write this before class

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\HttpUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\SingletonInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\Routing\UriBuilder;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer;
```

To Create link.

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE'] = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Controller\\TypoScriptFrontendController',
                        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'], $id, $type);
                        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->connectToDB();
                        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->initFEuser();
                        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->determineId();
                        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->initTemplate();
                        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getConfigArray();

                        $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');

                        $configurationManager = $objectManager->get(ConfigurationManager::class);
                        /** @var ContentObjectRenderer $contentObjectRenderer */
                        $contentObjectRenderer = $objectManager->get(ContentObjectRenderer::class);

                        $configurationManager->setContentObject($contentObjectRenderer);
                        $uriBuilder = $objectManager->get(UriBuilder::class);
                        $uriBuilder->injectConfigurationManager($configurationManager);
                        $targetPage = $singleConfig['targetpid'];

    //Initialize object explicitly to set contentObject member of class (required for TYPO3 10.X)
    $uriBuilder->initializeObject();


                        $uriBuilder->setTargetPageUid($targetPage)->setArguments(array());

                        $url = $uriBuilder->buildFrontendUri();
```

Comment: For some reason in a hook this stopped working
     $uriBuilder = $this->objectManager->get(UriBuilder::class);
     $uri = $uriBuilder->setTargetPageUid($myPage)->build();

Adding the contentObjectRenderer seems to have solved my problem indeed

Answer (score 0):

I have created a FrontendUriBuilderClass, with which you can create a Frontend-Link to a specific action with arguments and so on.

With this helper class it is possible to create a Typo3 frontend link in the backend. Feel free to use it!

```
/**
 * Class FrontendUriBuilder for creating a frontend link in the backend
 * @package PDVSysteme\Pdvsupportbase\Util
 */
class FrontendUriBuilder
{

private $pageId = 1;

private $extensionName = null;

private $pluginName = null;

private $actionName = null;

private $controllerName = null;

private $arguments = null;

private $host = null;

/**
 * FrontendUriBuilder constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
}

/**
 * @param int $pageId the target pageId
 * @return $this FrontendUriBuilder
 */
public function setPageId($pageId = 1){
    $this->pageId = $pageId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $extensionName 
 * @return $this FrontendUriBuilder
 */
public function setExtensionName($extensionName){
    $this->extensionName = $extensionName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $pluginName
 * @return $this FrontendUriBuilder
 */
public function setPlugin($pluginName){
    $this->pluginName = $pluginName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $actionName
 * @return $this FrontendUriBuilder
 */
public function setAction($actionName){
    $this->actionName = $actionName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $controllerName
 * @return $this FrontendUriBuilder
 */
public function setController($controllerName){
    $this->controllerName = $controllerName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param array $arguments like array('nameOfTheClass' => $instance) 
 * @return $this FrontendUriBuilder
 */
public function setArguments($arguments){
    $this->arguments = $arguments;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $host
 * @return $this FrontendUriBuilder
 */
public function setHost($host){
    $this->host = $host;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Build the URL 
 * @return string the url
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function build(){

    //set base
    $url = 'http://' . is_null($this->host)? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : $this->host;

    //set pageId
    $url = $url . '/index.php?id=' . $this->pageId;

    //set action
    if(!is_null($this->actionName)){
        $this->checkExtensionName();
        $this->checkPluginName();

        $url = $url . '&tx_' . $this->extensionName . '_' . $this->pluginName . '[action]=' . $this->actionName;
    }

    //set controller
    if(!is_null($this->controllerName)){
        $this->checkExtensionName();
        $this->checkPluginName();

        $url = $url . '&tx_' . $this->extensionName . '_' . $this->pluginName . '[controller]=' . ucfirst($this->controllerName);
    }

    //set arguments
    if(!is_null($this->arguments)) {
        $this->checkExtensionName();
        $this->checkPluginName();

        /**
         * @var $argument AbstractEntity
         */
        foreach ($this->arguments as $key => $argument) {
            $url = $url . '&tx_' . $this->extensionName . '_' . $this->pluginName . '[' . $key . ']=' . $argument->getUid();
        }
    }

    return $url;
}

private function checkExtensionName(){
    if(is_null($this->extensionName)){
        throw new \Exception("Extension name for FrontendUriBuilder not set!");
    }
}

private function checkPluginName(){
    if(is_null($this->pluginName)){
        throw new \Exception("Plugin name for FrontendUriBuilder not set!");
    }
}
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
$uriBuilder = new FrontendUriBuilder();
$uriBuilder->setPageId($pageUid)->setExtensionName($extensionName)->setPlugin($pluginName)->setAction($action)->setController($controller)->setArguments($arguments)->build();
```

The minimal call is:

```
$uriBuilder->build();
```

This will create a link to your main page with the uid 1.

If you want to add a action, controller or arguments to the url you need to set the "extensionName" and the "pluginName"!

Comment: cHash is missing

Answer (score -1):

What typo3 version?

Try use "build()" instead of "buildFrontendUri()" and let typo3 recognize the environment.
If you are inside a extbase controller, you should not need to "create" the uribuilder

```
$uri = $this->uriBuilder->reset()->setTargetPageUid($pageUid)->setCreateAbsoluteUri(TRUE)->setArguments($arguments)->build();
```